# Suppress "Identifier not allowed in Android"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-lint

For my application written in Kotlin I use backticked method names for tests, like this:

```
fun `API login error - don't save token or user`() {
```

It works, the tests compile and work without a problem, but Lint in Android Studio is marking those methods as error with message `Identifier not allowed in Android`.

Is there any way to suppress this so that the Lint check passes without errors and it's not marked with red underline in Android Studio?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it in code, but you can at least disable it in the IDE. Go to "File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | Illegal Android Identifier" and disable this inspection.

Answer (score 67):

Based on wnc_21 answer I found that it can be disabled for a specific scope, in my case it's only used in tests so there's that.

[image: Android Studio disable inspection for tests scope]

Answer (score 31):

Use:

```
@file:Suppress("IllegalIdentifier")
```

on the top of the file

Comment: This is a great answer as gives you more granular control and can be shared with other users that clone your code

Comment: It's more elegant and flexible way!

Answer (score 14):

I use

```
@Suppress("IllegalIdentifier")
```

example

```
@Suppress("IllegalIdentifier")
class SignUpTest {
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to suppress Lint checks from a Lint configuration file instead of annotating each and every single file or whatever with `@Suppress`. Note that it only affects builds executed from command line. I still haven't figured out how to make Android Studio use this configuration file for code inspections.

Android Gradle plugin has `lintConfig` property under `lintOptions` in its [DSL](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html).

It allows you to specify the path to a Lint configuration xml file. The feature is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#pref).

An example Lint config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <!-- Disable the given check in this project -->
    <issue id="IllegalIdentifier">
        <ignore path="**/androidTest/**" />
        <ignore path="**/test/**" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

This way, code inspection configuration is part of the codebase and is shared among all developers.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I intended to add a new test class into `test` package but added it to the `androidTest` by mistake.

It got solved after moving the class into the correct `test` package.